# Amount of integer $k$-tuples $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k)$

Tags: combinatorics

How many integer $k$-tuples $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k)$ are there such that
$1\leq x_1<x_2<x_3 < \ldots < x_k \leq n$
for fixed $n$?
I'm not sure how to start this. I know that this implies that $x_k \geq k$.
So there are $n-k+1$ choices for $x_k$. Now I'm not sure how to continue for $x_{k-1}$.

Comment: Is $n\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: Yes (I think $n\geq k$ might make more sense)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: How many ways are there to choose $k$ spots out of $n$? Why does this help?

Comment: $\binom{n}k$? I'm not sure how to relate this to the k-tuples. This is what we choose for $x_k$ right?

Comment: So what exactly does ${n\choose k}$ do?

Comment: It counts the number of ways to pick $k$ objects (in this case, $k$ integers) out of a set of $n$ (in this case, $n$ integers, since maximum is $n$), with unimportant order. I hope the interpretation is right

Comment: Yes, it is; now, consider a set of these numbers in ascending order

Comment: Ah I think I see it now...
So if I pick any set of $k$ different integers $x_1,\ldots,x_k$, from a set of $n$ integers, it is always possible to arrange in ascending order. The total ways to do this will then be $\binom{n}k$?

Comment: Yes, exactly! For each set of $k$ that you pick, simply assign to $x_1$ the smallest value of the $k$, $x_2$ the second smallest and so on...

Comment: Thank you for the kind hints and help!

Comment: Wouldn't this create "extra" tuples, though? For two different orderings of an equal amount of picked numbers, you could do the same procedure and assigning both orderings to the same tuple. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? We aren't ordering; simply pick a set of $k$ numbers. Then since they are distinct, one of them will be the smallest of the group, and one the largest, with the rest in between. The idea is that we simply let each $x_i$ correspond to the $i^{th}$ smallest of these

Comment: Sorry nevermind, I think my thinking was a bit off there. Don't want to bother OP any further with this discussion, too.